# How to effeciently compute the first, second, and third derivatives of live updating data?

Tags: algorithm, math, calculus

I have a running/decaying sum that updates over time with live data. I would like to efficiently compute the first, second, and third derivatives.

The simplest way I can think of doing this is to calculate deltas over some time difference in the running/decaying sum. e.g.

```
t_0 sum_0
t_1 sum_1
first_derivative = (sum_1 - sum_0) / (t_1 - t0)
```

I can continue this process further with the second and third derivatives, which I think should work, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

This running/decaying sum is not a defined function and relies on live updating data, so I can't just do a normal derivative.

Comment: finite differences is pretty old, established math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: thank you @duffymo, i was trying to find material on this, but didn't know the correct terminology

Comment: Glad it helped.  Wikipedia is a simple intro.  I'd advise you to look deeper.  You're working on a time series.  You will want to look at additional sources: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236987691_Using_derivatives_in_time_series_classification

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your real use case is, but it sounds like you're going about this the wrong way.  For most cases I can imagine, what you really want to do is:

1. First determine the continuous signal that your time series represents; and then
2. You can exactly calculate the derivatives of this signal at any point.

Since you have already decided that your time series represents exponential decay with discontinuous jumps, you have decided that all your derivatives are simply proportional to the current value and provide no extra information.

This probably isn't what you really want.

You would probably be better off applying a more sophisticated low-pass filter to your samples.  In situations like yours, where you receive intermittent updates, it can be convenient to design the [impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) as a weighted sum of exponential decays with different (and possibly complex) time scales.

If you use 4 or 5 exponentials, then you can ensure that the value and first 3 derivatives of the impulse response are all smooth, so none of the derivatives you have to report are discontinuous.

The impulse response of any all-pole IIR filter can be written as the sum of exponentials in this way, though "partial fraction decomposition", but I guess there is a lot of learning between you and there right now.  Those terms are all Googlable.

An example impulse response that would be smoother than an exponential decay, is this one, that's 0 in the first 3 derivatives:

5( e<sup>-t</sup> - 4e<sup>-2t</sup> + 6e<sup>-3t</sup> - 4e<sup>-4t</sup> + e<sup>-5t</sup> )

You can scale the decay times however you like.  It looks like this (from Wolfram Alpha):

[image: smooth plot]

Comment: the general use case I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the jerk of this live time series, and identify if/when the jerk hits a certain threshold. Can you clarify why the the time series would have discontinuous jumps? The time series represents a running sum which decays over time (and is incremented throughout the time period). That should be continuous right?

Comment: Each increment is a discontinuous jump

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you are looking to smooth out data AND to estimate rate of change.  But rate of change inherently amplifies noise.  Any solution is going to have to make some tradeoffs.

Here is a simple hack based on your existing technique.

First, let's look at a general version of a basic decaying sum.  Let's keep the following variables:

```
average_value
average_time
average_weight
```

And you have a decay rate `decay`.

To update with a new observation `(value, time)` you simply:

```
average_weight *= (1 - decay)**(time - average_time)
average_value = (average_value * average_weight + value) / (1 + average_weight)
average_time = (average_time * average_weight + time) / (1 + average_weight)
average_weight += 1
```

Therefore this moving average represents where your weight was some time ago.  The slower the decay, the farther back it goes and the more smoothed out it is. Given that we want rate of change, the when is going to matter.

Now let's look at a first derivative.  You have correctly put out a formula for estimating a first derivative.  But at what time is that estimated derivative at?  The answer turns out to be at time `(t_0 + t_1) / 2`.  Any other time you pick, it will be systematically off based on the third derivative.

So you can play around with it, but you can estimate a derivative based on any source of values and timestamps.  You can do it from your first derivative, or do it from a weighted average.  You can even combine them.  You can also do a running weighted average of the first derivative!  But whatever you do, you need to keep track of WHEN it is a derivative FOR.  (This is why I went through and discussed how far back a weighted average is, you need to think clearly about timestamping every piece of data you have, averaged or not.)

And now we have your second derivative.  You have all the same choices for the second derivative that you do for the first.  Except your measurements don't give a first derivative.

The third derivative follows the same pattern of choices.

However you do it, keep in mind the following.

1. Each derivative will be delayed.
2. The more up to date you keep them, the more noise will be a problem.
3. Make sure to think clearly about both what the measurement is, and when it is as of.

It may require experimentation to find what works best for your application.

Comment: my usecase uses a decaying running sum, so its of the form `running_sum = exp(-time_diff_s/decay_factor) * running_sum + new_sum`. It's basically the same as the average value calculation without normalizing with the weight. In this case, would the derivative still be the midpoint of t_0 & t_1, or would it be the instantaneous derivative at t_1?

Comment: @ajoseps In that case the same calculation as you did for the sum, but with timestamps instead of values.  That should be the time that your average is averaged around.